# Splitting layer with many polygons into independent shapefilles?

Tags: qgis, splitting

Is there any way to save many shapefile, which are **not** multipolygons, into shapefile, and then iterate over them?

I have shapefile with plot polygons and I want to have each one independent in order to build a grid for each one of them and to use rotate in order to make the grid look good inside the polygon.

This is what I have right now

[image: example]

**My end goal** is to use the Model builder to iterate those polygons and to create for each one of them a grid.

Comment: So you want each polygon saved as a separate shapefile?